# How to read the indexes from the prediction output of predict.ranger, R

Tags: r, random-forest

Using the [ranger](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ranger/index.html) package I run the following script:

```
 rf <- ranger(Surv(time, Y) ~ ., data = train_frame[1:50000, ], write.forest = TRUE, num.trees = 100)

test_frame <-  train_frame[50001:100000, ]
preds <- predict(rf, test_frame)
chfs <- preds$chf
plot(chfs[1, ])
```

The cumulative hazard function has indexes 1 - 36 on the X-axis. Obviously this corresponds with time, but I'm not sure how: my time of observation variable ranges from a minimum of 0 to a maximum of 399. What is the mapping between the original data and the predicted output from `predict.ranger`, and how can I operationalize this to quantify degree of risk for a given subject after a given length of time?

Here's a sample of what my time/event data looks like:

```
       Y  time
   <int> <dbl>
1      1   358
2      0    90
3      0   162
4      0    35
5      0   307
6      0    69
7      0   184
8      0    24
9      0   366
10     0    33
```

And here's what the CHF of the first subject looks like: 
[image]
Can anyone help me connect the dots? There are no row or columns names on the `"matrix"` object that is `preds$chf`.

Comment: What does `str(preds)` look like?  When I run your code with the model as `rf <- ranger(Surv(time, status) ~ ., data = veteran, write.forest = TRUE, num.trees = 100)`, my `chfs` has rows and columns.  I'm surprised you can use `importance = 'impurity'` with survival.  Also, .  Anyway you can make this reproducible? I'm surprised you can use `importance = 'impurity'` with survival

Comment: This was an old line of code. `importance = 'impurity` did indeed throw an error. I not in front of my workspace just now, but `str(preds)` is a named list of class `ranger.predict`. My CHFs and survival functions are also matrices. @mnwright's answer below hits the nail on the head.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the prediction object is vector called `unique.death.times` containing the time points where the CHF and survival estimates are computed. The `chf` matrix has observations in the rows and these time points in the columns, same for `survival`.

Reproducible example:

```
library(survival)
library(ranger)

## Split the data
n <- nrow(veteran)
idx <- sample(n, 2/3*n)
train <- veteran[idx, ]
test <- veteran[-idx, ]

## Grow RF and predict
rf <- ranger(Surv(time, status) ~ ., train, write.forest = TRUE)
preds <- predict(rf, test)

## Example CHF plot
plot(preds$unique.death.times, preds$chf[1, ])

## Example survival plot
plot(preds$unique.death.times, preds$survival[1, ])
```

Setting `importance = "impurity"` for survival forests should throw an error.

Comment: nailed it, thanks! and yep, `importance = 'impurity'` does indeed through an error. this was from an older script.